# V infinity matching software for gravity assists?

Tags: gravity-assist, software

Is their software someone has already written for hyperbolic velocity matching of porkchop plots to be used to figure out ballistic gravity assists? Doing this in single threaded python requires using a full root solver over thousands of data points.

Comment: KSPTOT might be helpful, the program has a config for Principia + RSS/RO. Requires a somewhat beefy computer for computational time.

Comment: My software does this, haven't found a way around it other than sparser data and some filtering. It is the longest/slowest part of my process.

Comment: @fasterthanlight Have used KSPTOT before. Great, but has two drawbacks. It doesn't use ephemeris, so loses sync after few years. It also arrives at local solutions using genetic algorithm rather than evaluating entire solution space.